# Haskell standard function (or simple composition) for "mjoin"?

Tags: haskell

This seems a long shot, but recently I've had a need for the following:

```
mjoin :: (Monoid b, Monad m) => m b -> m b -> m b
mjoin a b = do
  a' <- a
  b' <- b
  return $ mappend a' b'
```

The example use is this:

```
> mjoin (Just [1,2,3]) (Just [4, 5, 6])
Just [1,2,3,4,5,6]
> mjoin (Just [1,2,3]) Nothing
Nothing
> mjoin Nothing (Just [4, 5, 6])
Nothing
```

In other words, if either parameters are `Nothing`, then return `Nothing`. Else, return `Just` and the appended values.

Is there a standard function for this or a simpler formulation, perhaps with `>>=`?

Comment: A slight simplification would be `liftM2 mappend`.

Comment: @sabauma: Why not write that as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
mjoin :: (Monoid b, Monad m) => m b -> m b -> m b
mjoin = liftM2 mappend
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was covered somewhere.

Comment: @Ana This also means that you don't really have to define `mjoin` as a function, you can just do `liftA2 mappend (Just [1, 2, 3]) (Just [4, 5, 6])`. (I suggest `liftA2` since you're not really doing monad stuff, you're just doing applicative stuff.)

Comment: (As long as the types being used are instances of both, which is almost always the case now)